# ErrorCannotUseItemIdForFolderId when following DeltaLink

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to use a DeltaLink to get Event changes from a Calendar. It works good but sometimes I get an `HTTP 400 - ErrorCannotUseItemIdForFolderId` error.

Oddly enough, I get a success response when I send the same DeltaLink the next day.

What's wrong with this DeltaLink?

Request:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/calendars/{id}/calendarView/delta?$deltatoken={token}
```

Response:

```
"error": {
   "code": "ErrorCannotUseItemIdForFolderId",
   "message": "Expected a folder Id but received an item Id.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "a704ea5f-2677-4f38-88c0-aaca240b4cb8",
        "date": "2019-05-30T16:40:46"
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Thanks for your help. Is it a known issue?